# Advantages of nuSOAP WebService?

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

I've been writing a demo web service in PHP using nuSOAP.

I wanted to know what is the advantage of nuSOAP to SOAP PHP5 class.

Also, this is a test web service to use as a model.

I was wondering which were the typical scenarios (general to Webservices, not just PHP) I should test out e.g. providing a web method that returns an object from the server returning a list of items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only advantage IMO is that it is **a set of PHP classes and No PHP extensions are required**.

So, if your webhost uses an older version of PHP or does *NOT* have SoapClient extension installed, you can use this.

To test the webservice, there is an awesome tool: [**soapUI**](http://www.soapui.org).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I've been given that tip, soapUI rocks. But I wanted to know if there's a basic test suite for WSs.

Comment: @ign, If you want something basic, go for SoapUI FREE version. That is the lite version of the thing.

Comment: I got that already, it's great. What I mean is that perhaps there is a basic array of functionality to do a proof of concept WS. What would that be?

Answer (score 0):

I could tell one .

Nusoap could provide wsdl uri.

e.g.

https://www.domain.com/nusoap?wsdl